# Making a POST request from computer to phone on same local network

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, tcp

I am trying to make a post request from my desktop computer onto a Unity App with a http listener on my phone.

The Unity app listens on `0.0.0.0:4444`. I send data to this via my python application using

```
x = requests.post("http://192.168.0.98:4444", data = somestring))
```

where `192.168.0.98` is the ip address of my phone. The two devices are connected to the same network. I have tried - turning on USB debugging, pairing the devices via adb and the 6-digit pairing code, connecting the devices via adb and the instructions here https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless.

The application works perfectly when I am running Unity on my desktop on the same computer as the python code, but when I run it on my phone, my python code encounters.

`HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.0.98', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000253FEB996A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))`

Answer (score 1):

Well I just solved this two minutes later, just had to change the listener to 192.168.0.98 as well